# vue-virtual-scroller Module parse failing

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2

Hello I have a strange error when trying to build my vue2 project.
I am using "vue-virtual-scroller": "^1.0.10"
I tried changing the version but I got the same error message.

Building on my local machine or in a docker container on my machine is ok, and when I try to build it on a remote one I got the error.
The versions of node and npm are the same on both machines -
node v21.0.0
npm 10.2.0

here is the error message:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/vue-virtual-scroller/dist/vue-virtual-scroller.esm.js
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (61:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| },
 props: {
| ...props,
| itemSize: {
| type: Number,
@ ./src/main.js
```

I tried changing the versions of the library, I checked the node and npm versions, everything seems to be the same as local.

SOLVED
I used the exact version and this solved the issue.
version is 1.0.10

Comment: Did you tried to delete node_modules directory entirely and then run install again?

Comment: Yes, I have that in the docker script.
RUN rm -rf ./npm_modules

Comment: Is it `RUN rm -rf ./npm_modules` not `node_modules` ?

Comment: let me try again with that, thanks

Comment: didn't help, I got the same error again, I was really hoping this is the problem.

Comment: Can you send your package.json?

Comment: ok, I changed the version again to the concrete 1.0.10, without the "^" and this solved the problem.